# How to get my custom sorted colors to work in my jframe?

Tags: java, swing, colors, jframe, paint

I am using custom colors to make a small app to show randomly made colors, the colors would be ovals and the RGB component numbers underneath it.  The outer JFrame will have 3 tabs to sort the colors by saturation least to most in terms of RGB, ex: pink is lighter than red so it would be catagorized first in the list under red.  But I seem to have a problem sending the sorted color data between the driver to sort the data and driver to draw the ovals.  I get the error message "cannot find symbol".  If anyone point out what I am doing wrong, it would be a great help.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;



public class Graphic extends JFrame
{

      public static void main(String[] args) 
      {
          ArrayList<Colorsorter> derp = new ArrayList<Colorsorter>();  
         Colorsorter oneColor = new Colorsorter(0,0,0);
         int R;
          int G;
          int B;
          Random colorgen = new Random();
          for(int n = 0; n < 50; n++)
          {
             R = colorgen.nextInt(256);
             G = colorgen.nextInt(256);
              B = colorgen.nextInt(256);
              oneColor = new Colorsorter(R,G,B);
               derp.add(oneColor);
          }

    }
   public Graphic()
    {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         setSize(500,1000);
         setVisible(true);
    }
   public void paint(Graphics page)
   {  
       for(int h = 0; h < 10; h++)
       {
           for(int l = 0; l < 5; l++)
            { 
               page.setColor(new Color(255,215,0));
             page.drawOval(50+(l*100), 40+(h*100), 100, 40);
                page.fillOval(50+(l*100), 40+(h*100), 100, 40);
             page.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0));
             page.drawString("Red: " + oneColor.getRed()+ " " + "Green: " + oneColor.getGreen() + " " + "Blue: " + oneColor.getBlue(), 20+(100*l), 90+(100*h));
            }
        }

   }
}
```

// The DRIVER

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Colorsorter extends Color implements Comparable <Colorsorter>
{
   public Colorsorter()
    {
       super(0,0,0);
    }

   public Colorsorter (int r, int g, int b)
   {
       super(r,g,b);
    }

    public String toString()
   {
       return("Red: " + getRed() + "    " + "Green: " + getGreen() + "    " + "Blue: " + getBlue() + "    " + "\n");
    }

    public int compareTo (Colorsorter colorsort)
    {
      return getRed() - colorsort.getRed();
    }
}
```

I get the error on line 44:
Graphic.java:44: error: cannot find symbol
page.drawString("Red: " + oneColor.getRed()+ " " + "Green: " + oneColor.getGreen()....;
                                                                                                                                                       ................................................................... ^

Comment: RE: *I get the error message "cannot find symbol"* - Please provide all the details about the error: what `symbol`, in what `line of code`, etc.

Comment: Are you able to run this program ? Because there is an error in your `Graphic` class. `oneColor` is not accessible in paint method because it is not a class field but rather defined inside `main` function.

Comment: No I have not been able to run it.  I ran a similar program a while ago using just text, but I am now writing the program so you can actually see it become organized.

Comment: How would I fix this, do I throw in an exception?

Comment: @Kreg, To fix this error, you need to define them as class fields. So that they are accessible from all class functions.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `oneColor` is only visible in the scope of the `static` `main` method of `Graphic` so is not available in the `paint` method, hence the *cannot find symbol* compilation error message.

To take advantage of Swing optimized paint model, custom painting is done by overriding  `paintComponent` rather than `paint`. Also override `super.paintComponent` to update child components.

Therefore move the custom paint functionality to a new component that subclasses `JComponent`, using `oneColor` as a class member variable.

Links:

- [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)
- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)